# why FunctionN(0-22) ProductN(1-22) TupleN(1-22)?

Tags: scala

The api has FunctionN(0-22) ProductN(1-22) TupleN(1-22) 
the question is:
1.why the number is end of 22? why not 21 or 23?
2.why Function is start with 0 ? but Product and Tuple are not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does not make sense to have a `Product` or a `Tuple` that contains no elements. These would be equivalent to `Unit`.

`Function0` exists because a function does not necessarily take arguments (e.g. in the case of by-name arguments).

In the case of `Tuple22` and `Function22` I cannot tell why the Scala team chose 22 as a maximum but it definitely is awkward to have tuples with that many members or functions that take more than 22 arguments.

It could be though that there is a restriction on how many arguments to a method the JVM can handle.

Comment: There's no technical reason to stop at 22, actually. It's automatically generated, but it had to stop at _some_ number. People have used the creating scripts to generate bigger tuples and functions.

Comment: You are off by one: that is why *they* invented `Function0` and `Unit` - so there are actually 23 of each.

Comment: @Landei probably inspired by Jim Carrey's movie?