# Why does the Scala library only defines tuples up to Tuple22?

Tags: scala

I'm curious if anyone knows why the Scala library stops at `22` with its tuple type `Tuple22`?
Does the mysterious number `22` have a special hidden meaning?
Is this an internal joke of some kind?

Comment: They felt that 23 would be a bit too much... ;)

Comment: it's 22 for consistency with functions. And arity from 0-22 are 23 different functions and we all know what that means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_(film)

Comment: possible duplicate of [why FunctionN(0-22) ProductN(1-22) TupleN(1-22)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618016/why-functionn0-22-productn1-22-tuplen1-22)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is not new, see http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Why-tuples-only-to-22-td1945314.html or [why FunctionN(0-22) ProductN(1-22) TupleN(1-22)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618016/why-functionn0-22-productn1-22-tuplen1-22)

AFAIK there is no "technical" explanation for it, they simply had to stop somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Limit 22 is one of the [dropped](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/limit22.html) features of dotty (Scala 3) which now allows tuples of arbitrary arity:

> The limits of 22 for... the maximal number of fields in tuple types have been
>   dropped... tuples beyond `Tuple22` are erased to a new trait `scala.TupleXXL`.

[For example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/x6oQThhURuitFt9qjCzJww),

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tuple: Tuple = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25")
    println(tuple.getClass)
    println(tuple.size)
  }
}
```

outputs

```
class scala.TupleXXL
25
```

For further examples see [Add tests for the current tuple API #7633](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/7633)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has to do with difficulties in implementing a static type system while having variadic (arbitrary-argument) functions. I believe `apply` can be written in Scala (though not in Haskell, at least not elegantly).

Answer (score 2):

The case class limit has been lifted in 2.11 https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2305

Comment: In Scala 2.11.8: `error: too many elements for tuple: 24, allowed: 22
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
^`