# Scala: Array, List, Seq to argument function

Tags: scala

How can this be automated?
(Insert the elements of the array into the arguments of the function)

```
def func(d1: Boolean, d2: Boolean, d3: Boolean, d4: Boolean) = ???

val data = Array(true, true, false, false)

func(
  data(0),
  data(1),
  data(2),
  data(3)
)
```

Comment: Scala has an `apply` method that does this doesn't it? In most languages (that I know at least), the function that achieves this is called `apply`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `apply` is used for `object`s (types, really). One could create a helper object that does something similar to tuple unwrapping in Python, but otherwise this isn't going to get much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

If I undestand your question correctly:

```
def func(d: Boolean*) = {
  d.map( if (_) "yes" else "no" ).foreach(println)
}

val data = Array(true, true, false, false)

func(data: _*)
yes
yes
no
no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'splat' operator with a varargs argument:

```
def func(args : Boolean*) = {
  args foreach println
}

val data = Array(true, true, false, false)

func(data: _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to convert your list to a tuple:

```
scala> def func(d1: Boolean, d2: Boolean, d3: Boolean, d4: Boolean) = s"$d1 $d2 $d3 $d4"
func: (d1: Boolean, d2: Boolean, d3: Boolean, d4: Boolean)String

scala> val ff = func _
ff: (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) => String = $$Lambda$1151/1744486549@5a13f1f7

scala> val data = (true,false,true,true)
data: (Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) = (true,false,true,true)

scala> ff.tupled(data)
res8: String = true false true true
```

Comment: `data` is a tuple, not an `Array` or `Seq`

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov My post begins with `If you manage to convert your list to a tuple`

Comment: I assume OP is able to search SO for questions with answers.

Comment: Oh, c'mon. OP would not register and ask the question, if he/she could search SO

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a "tupled" function, just like in Assen Kolov's answer:

   ```
   def func(d1: Boolean, d2: Boolean, d3: Boolean, d4: Boolean) = ???

   val f = func _
   ```
2. then create a tuple from your `Seq`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722860/convert-a-scala-list-to-a-tuple) shows how to do it in a type-safe way.
3. And call your function `f` with a tuple argument.