# How to transform a list of mixed type to tuple of lists of same type

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

Two objects extend a base object like this:

```
trait Component

class ComponentA extends Component

class ComponentB extends Component
```

Let's say I have some objects instantiated:

```
val a = new ComponentA
val a2 = new ComponentA
val b = new ComponentB
```

I'm given a list of type `Component`, like this:

```
val components = List[Components](a, a2, b)
```

What I want to do is have a function that takes a list of mixed type and transforms it into an n-tuple of lists containing only one type. So for example, `components` would break down like this:

```
transform.apply(components) = (List(a, a2), List(b))
```

The nonfunctional, grotesque, Frankensteinian way to do this is:

```
def apply(c: List[Component]) = {
  var aComponents = new ListBuffer[ComponentA]()
  var bComponents = new ListBuffer[ComponentB]()

  for (c <- components) {
    c match {
      case aType: ComponentA => aComponents += aType
      case bType: ComponentB => bComponents += bType
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  aComponents -> bComponents

}
```

Obviously there's tons of drawbacks to this method:

1. In my case, I have two component types. But this case does not generalize to produce an n-tuple for n-components.
2. It's not functional. (Uses mutable `ListBuffer`, doesn't leverage the `Collections` library.)
3. It's ugly. Like really ugly. I cannot over-emphasize how ugly it is.

Is there a way I can get this accomplished with FP in Scala? My initial thought was to use some sort of `groupBy` function with an internal case/match for type inspection?

Comment: There seems a typo in `val components = List[Components](a, a2, b)`. It should be `val components = List[Component](a, a2, b)` instead.

Comment: Are you dead set on returning a tuple of lists? Is there any reason a List of Lists, or a Map[Class, List] wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why not just use the `groupBy` with your class like:

```
c.groupBy(_.getClass).values
```

This will already give you a `List` of `Lists` with the grouped instances in it. Getting a tuple is more complicated as you need to know the type beforehand. There is solutions using Shapeless ([Convert a Scala list to a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722860/convert-a-scala-list-to-a-tuple)) but not sure you really have to go that far as your original solution seems to work without an actual tuple.

Comment: Have thought about using Typeless, but it seems like overkill. Thanks! This is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `foldRight` to traverse the `components` list to assemble the `(List[ComponentA], List[ComponentB])` tuple:

```
components.foldRight( (List[ComponentA](), List[ComponentB]()) )(
  (x, acc) => x match {
    case x: ComponentA => (x :: acc._1, acc._2)
    case x: ComponentB => (acc._1, x :: acc._2)
    case _ => acc
  }
)
// res1: (List[ComponentA], List[ComponentB]) =
//   (List(ComponentA@24a298a6, ComponentA@74fe5966), List(ComponentB@2bfbffb2))
```

Comment: This will be very slow on large lists due to using `:+` on `List`s recursively.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Alexey Romanov.  I had the same concern but chose not to use `::` + `reverse` for brevity.  Agreed that performance should be a priority.  Solution revised to using `foldRight` instead of `foldLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use collect:

```
val aList = c.collect { case a: ComponentA => a }
val bList = c.collect { case b: ComponentB => b }
val res = (aList, bList)
```

Comment: It is `val bList = c.collect { case b: ComponentB => b } `, a small typo anyway.

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Note that this goes over the list twice (or N times if you have N subtypes). For large lists this may be a problem.