# Flatten value in paired RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a paired RDD that looks like

```
(a1, (a2, a3))
(b1, (b2, b3))
...
```

I want to flatten the values to obtain

```
(a1, a2, a3)
(b1, b2, b3)
...
```

Currently I'm doing

```
rddData.map(x => (x._1, x._2._1, x._2._2))
```

Is there a better way of performing the conversion? The above solution gets ugly if `value` contains many elements instead of just 2.

Comment: your approach looks good. are there any reason you looking for an alternative ?

Comment: @RahulSharma. Mainly curiosity because my way looks too "manual". What if `value` contains much more than 2 elements (added to the question)?

Answer (score 3):

When I'm trying to avoid all the ugly underscore number stuff that comes with tuple manipulation I like to use case notation:

```
rddData.map { case (a, (b, c)) => (a, b, c) }
```

You can also give your variables meaningful names to make your code self documenting and the use of curly braces means you have fewer nested parentheses.

EDIT:
The map { case ... } pattern is pretty compact and can be used for surprisingly deep nested tuples as long as the structure is known at compile time.  If you absolutely, positively cannot know the structure of the tuple at compile time, then here is some hacky, slow code that, probably, can flatten any arbitrarily nested tuple... as long as there are no more than 23 elements in total.  It works by recursivly converting each element of the tuple to a list, flatmap-ing it to a single list, then using scary reflection to convert the list back into a tuple as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722860/convert-a-scala-list-to-a-tuple).

```
def flatten(b:Product): List[Any] = { 
  b.productIterator.toList.flatMap {
    case x: Product => flatten(x)
    case y: Any => List(y)
  }
}

def toTuple[Any](as:List[Any]):Product = {
  val tupleClass = Class.forName("scala.Tuple" + as.size)
  tupleClass.getConstructors.apply(0).newInstance(as.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]):_*).asInstanceOf[Product]
}

rddData.map(t => toTuple(flatten(t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way. The 1st answer is equivalent to:

```
val abc2 = xyz.map{ case (k, v) => (k, v._1, v._2) }
```

which is equivalent to your own example.