# scala collection Seq override mkstring

Tags: scala, tostring

How can I override

```
Seq(Seq(1,2), Seq(2,3)).mkString("::")
```

to return

```
(1, 2)::(2, 3)
```

instead of:

```
List(1, 2)::List(2, 3)
```

## edit

It looks like it boils down to:

```
Seq((1,2), (2,3)).mkString("::")
```

how can I convert the nested sequence to tuples?
(As this prints nicely without the type identifier). But a tuple would not work [Convert a Scala list to a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722860/convert-a-scala-list-to-a-tuple)

Comment: "Tuple" is XY-distraction. If you want strings, then `map` it to strings in the format that you need, then concatenate with `::` using `mkString`.

Comment: But how can I get rid of the `List` prefix for each nested list item?

Comment: `Seq(Seq(1,2), Seq(2,3)).map(_.mkString("(",", ",")")).mkString("::")`

Comment: In exactly the same way that you can get rid of `StuffYouDontNeed` in `Seq(Seq(1,2), Seq(2,3)).map(_.mkString("StuffYouDontNeed(", ",", ")")).mkString("::")` - if you don't need it, then don't put it into the result string.