# Convert List[String] to List[(String,String)] by splitting on delimiter

Tags: list, scala, split, pattern-matching

I am trying to split a string from a CSV on a method. There are two values seperated by one comma.

I use map to create a new `List[(String, String)]` but when I split, it returns an `Array`. If I use `.toList` immediately after the `split(",")` then it joins them back together, returning a `List(String)` which makes the split obsolete, and if I use `.toList` outside of the map, then it returns `List[Array(String)]`.

When I use `splitAt(2)` it returns the correct datatype but it doesn't split at the comma. Is there a way for the split function to split into two `Lists` rather than `Array`?

**EDIT**: Code:

```
val getlines = some csv...

val splitList = getlines.map(_.split(",").toList) // returns List[List(String)]
val splitList = getlines.map(_.split(",")).toList // returns List[Array(String)]
val splitList = getlines.map(_.split(",")) // returns List[Array(String)]
```

Comment: it's not very clear tbh...can you try to rephrase and add examples so that we can try to help you?

Comment: Please show the code that is causing the problem so that we have a better idea of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Changed it guys

Comment: try with flatMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Convert a Scala list to a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21768342/5205022), assuming you have `List[String]` like so

```
val lines =
  List(
    "a1,a2",
    "b1,b2",
    "c1,c3"
  )
```

then

```
lines.map(_.split(",") match { case Array(a, b) => (a, b) })
```

outputs

```
res1: List[(String, String)] = List((a1,a2), (b1,b2), (c1,c3))
```

However, this might fail at runtime if you have a bad row, say `"a1,"`, in which case consider wrapping it in a `Try`, or filtering out the bad rows like so

```
lines.flatMap(_.split(",") match {
  case Array(a, b) => Some((a, b))
  case _ => None
})
```

Comment: This did get the method to be accepted on the return type, but it returns '0' when checking the size of the new list. I think it filters everything out

Comment: I did some playing around and I fixed it! Thank you SO MUCH, I have been stuck on this for three days.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a string with comma:

```
scala> val csvLine = "something,another"
csvLine: String = something,another

scala> csvLine.split(",")
res3: Array[String] = Array(something, another)

scala> res3.toList
res4: List[String] = List(something, another)
```

this works as expected

if you do have a list of rows, use flatMap:

```
scala> val csv = List("line1,column2", "line2,column2")
csv: List[String] = List(line1,column2, line2,column2)

scala> csv.flatMap(line => line.split(","))
res5: List[String] = List(line1, column2, line2, column2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but wouldn't it be a List[Array(String)] if it wasn't over multiple lines in the repo? I'm trying to do it as a function but it doesn't give me this output

Comment: @RonnieLightweightbabyColeman You don't mention a repo or multiple lines in the question. Please improve the question and add some code so that we can understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: if you have multiple lines, try with flatMap. I updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately this returns List[String] for me