# Converting a Seq[Int] to a tuple with predetermined size, in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples, sequence

So I have a Sequence of Ints representing notes on a guitar, now since this guitar will have 6 strings, I also have a function parameter that takes 6 Ints in a tuple like this:

```
pos: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
```

After have looked for "Scala seq to tuple" on Google and having found nothing useful I ask here.

How do I pass my `Seq[Int]` as a tuple into my function parameter most effectively?

Comment: @voila17 Yes, specifically this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722860/convert-a-scala-list-to-a-tuple/18426026#18426026

Answer (score 1):

Can you avoid the `Seq` in the first place and have a `Tuple` since the very beginning?

If not, the best you can do is pattern match the `Seq`

```scala
seq match {
  case Seq(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6) => Some(f((n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)))
  case _ => None
}
```