# Java List of() static method

Tags: java, collections, java-9

I am executing below code snippet

```
System.out.println(List.of(1, 2).getClass());  
System.out.println(List.of(1, 2, 3).getClass());
```

output of this code is;

```
class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List2  
class java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN
```

I am expecting `java.util.ImmutableCollections$List3` as output for the second statement because there is `of()` method which takes three parameter, Why java creating `ImmutableCollections$ListN` but not `ImmutableCollections$List3`?

Edited: It is Java-9 question. There are total 11 overloaded of() methods in List interface each of them takes variable number of parameters from zero to 10 and eleventh one takes varargs to handle N list. So I am expecting List0 to List10 implementation for first 10 overloaded methods, but it is returning ListN with three parameters. Yes, it is implementation detail but just curious to know more information of this.

Comment: It's an implementation detail - it's worth asking yourself why you'd *expect* anything in particular. In a future version, the second could return a List3, or the first could return a ListN.

Comment: Do you know *why* the call in the first case returns a `ImmutableCollections$List2`? What do you expect when calling it with 200 arguments? Are you (incorrectly) expecting `ImmutableCollections$List200` to be returned?

Comment: It seems that the creators of Java decided to provide only the classes `ImmutableCollections.List0`, `ImmutableCollections.List1`, `ImmutableCollections.List2` and `ImmutableCollections.ListN`

Comment: FWIW, in Java 11 `List0`, `List1` and `List2` will be gone. There'll be just a `List12` and a `ListN`. Reference: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193128

Comment: @StefanZobel Right, and `ListN` will be used for an empty list

Answer (score 14):

The main reason to have several different private implementations of `List` is to save space.

Consider an implementation that stores its elements in an array. (This is essentially what `ListN` does.) In Hotspot (64-bit with compressed object pointers, each 4 bytes) each object requires a 12-byte header. The `ListN` object has a single field containing the array, for a total of 16 bytes. An array is a separate object, so that has another 12-byte header plus a 4-byte length. That's another 16 bytes, not counting any actual elements stored. If we're storing two elements, they take 8 bytes. That brings the total to 40 bytes for storing a two-element list. That's quite a bit of overhead!

If we were to store the elements of a small list in fields instead of an array, that object would have a header (12 bytes) plus two fields (8 bytes) for a total of 20 bytes -- half the size. For small lists, there's a considerable savings with storing elements in fields of the `List` object itself instead of in an array, which is a separate object. This is what the old `List2` implementation did. It's recently been superseded by the `List12` implementation, which can store lists of one or two elements in fields.

Now, in the API there are 12 overloaded `List.of()` methods: zero to ten fixed args plus varargs. Shouldn't there be corresponding `List0` through `List10` and `ListN` implementations?

There could be, but there doesn't necessarily have to be. An early prototype of these implementations had the optimized small list implementations tied to the APIs. So the zero, one, and two fixed arg `of()` methods created instances of `List0`, `List1`, and `List2`, and the varargs `List.of()` method created an instance of `ListN`. This was fairly straightforward, but it was quite restrictive. We wanted to be able to add, remove, or rearrange implementations at will. It's considerably more difficult to change APIs, since we have to remain compatible. Thus, we decided to decouple things so that the number of arguments in the APIs was largely independent of the implementation instantiated underneath.

In JDK 9 we ended up with the 12 overloads in the API, but only four implementations: field-based implementations holding 0, 1, and 2 elements, and an array-based implementation holding an arbitrary number. Why not add  more field-based implementations? Diminishing returns and code bloat. Most lists have few elements, and there's an exponential dropoff in the occurrences of lists as the number of elements gets larger. The space savings get relatively smaller compared to an array-based implementation. Then there's the matter of maintaining all those extra implementations. Either they'd have to be entered directly in the source code (bulky) or we'd switch over to a code generation scheme (complex). Neither seemed justified.

Our startup performance guru [Claes Redestad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397895/claes-redestad) did some measurements and found that there was a speedup in having *fewer* list implementations. The reason is *megamorphic dispatch*. Briefly, if the JVM is compiling the code for a virtual call site and it can determine that only one or two different implementations are called, it can optimize this well. But if there are many different implementations that can be called, it has to go through a slower path. (See this article for [Black Magic](https://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch/) details.)

For the list implementations, it turns out that we can get by with fewer implementations without losing much space. The `List1` and `List2` implementations can be combined into a two-field `List12` implementation, with the second field being null if there's only one element. We only need one zero-length list, since it's immutable! For a zero-length list, we can get rid of `List0` just use a `ListN` with a zero-length array. It's bigger than an old `List0` instance, but we don't care, since there's only one of them.

These changes just went into the JDK 11 mainline. Since the API is completely decoupled from the implementations, there is no compatibility issue.

There are additional possibilities for future enhancements. One potential optimization is to fuse an array onto the end of an object, so the object has a fixed part and a variable-length part. This will avoid the need for an array object's header, and it will probably improve locality of reference. Another potential optimization is with value types. With value types, it might be possible to avoid heap allocation entirely, at least for small lists. Of course, this is all highly speculative. But if new features come along in the JVM, we can take advantage of them in the implementations, since they're are entirely hidden behind the API.

Answer (score 8):

`ListN` is the all-purpose version. `List2` is an optimised implementation. There is no such optimised implementation for a list with three elements.

There currently exist* optimised versions for lists and sets with zero, one and two elements. `List0`, `List1`, `List2`, `Set0` etc...

There's also an optimised implementation for an empty map, `Map0`, and for a map containing a single key-value pair, `Map1`.

Discussion relating to how these implementations are able to provide performance improvements can been seen in [JDK-8166365](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166365).

---

<sub>*bear in mind this is an implementation detail which may be subject to change, and actually [is due to change fairly soon](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-March/052183.html)</sub>

Comment: "bear in mind this is an implementation detail which may be subject to change". Yes, it will change. They are going to replace List1 and List2 with a single List12 implementation: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-March/052183.html

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Very interesting. Thanks! I've edited that into my answer

Answer (score 3):

Neither `ImmutableCollections$List2` nor `ImmutableCollections$ListN` is generated at runtime. There are four classes already written:

```
static final class List0<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> { ... }
static final class List1<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> { ... }
static final class List2<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> { ... }
static final class ListN<E> extends AbstractImmutableList<E> { ... }
```

Starting with `of(E e1, E e2, E e3)` and up to `of(E e1, ..., E e10)` an instance of `ImmutableCollections.ListN<>` is going to be created.

> Why java creating `ImmutableCollections$ListN` but not `ImmutableCollections$List3`?

The designers have probably decided that `3` and `N` cases are similar and it's not worth writing a separate class for `3`. Apparently, they won't get enough benefits from `$List3`, `$List7`, `$List10` as they have got from the `$List0`, `$List1`, and `$List2` versions. They are specifically-optimised.

Currently, 4 classes cover 10 methods. If they decided to add some more methods (e.g. [with 22 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241441/why-does-the-scala-library-only-defines-tuples-up-to-tuple22)), there would still be these 4 classes.
Imagine you are writing 22 classes for 22 methods. How much unnecessary code duplication would it involve?

Comment: and regarding your last point, you've gotta draw the line somewhere. If they were to add a `List3` then why not a `List4`, 5, 6...?

Comment: Could you please clarify why this is not a duplicate of the previously marked question? The answer here adds nothing more to the answer made by ZhekaKozlov on the existing thread.

Comment: @nullpointer, OP already knows that `ListX` types exist and their instances are returned from `List.of`

Answer (score 1):

Those are both *classes* that are being returned. i.e. there is a separate class for `ImmutableCollections$List2` and `ImmutableCollections$ListN` (the $ indicates an inner class)

This is an implementation detail, and (presumably) List2 exists for (possibly) some optimisation reason. I suspect if you look at the source (via your IDE or similar) you'll see two distinct inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet rightly mentioned, it is an implementation detail. The specification of `List.of` says that it returns an immutable List, and that's all that matters.

The developers probably decided that they could provide efficient implementations of one-element (`List1`) and two-element lists (`List2`), and that all other sizes could be handled by a single type (`ListN`). This could change at some point in the future - maybe they will introduce a `List3` at some point, maybe not.

As per the rules of polymorphism and encapsulation, none of this matters. As long as the returned object is a List, you should not concern yourself with its actual implementation.